# Seasonality test for poissonian counts

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, seasonality, poisson-process

I have a count $N_i$ of rare evevents for each season, where $i$ identifies the season. The counts' rates are not high enough to justify a normal distribution aproximation of the poissonian.

I want to test the null hypothesis of uniform rate trhoughout the year, but I do not have an independent reference value for the yearly rate.

I've already checked if a count from one season is compatible with the one from a different season with a simple compatibility check:
$$|N_i-N_j| \leq 3(\sqrt{N_i} + \sqrt{N_j})$$
Where I used $\sqrt{N_i}$ as the stdev of the count $N_i$.

Are there any better tests I could do?